# jQuery: Record element changes in Array and check how it was by its index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Every click is one step and will add a child div in `.test`, I keep all the element changes in `step` array

I wanted it to look like this:

```
Array step [0]        = before click, 
Array step [0,01]     = after one click, 
Array step [0,01,012] = aftert two click
```

but it works like this:

```
Array step [0]        = before click, 
Array step [0,11]     = after one click, 
Array step [0,11,222] = aftert two click
```

[fiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cheeray/j4L5hrex/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="test"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="change()">Count Child Element</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var step =[];               // step is a record of changes in #test.
step.push($('.test'))        //step[0] is status of .test at very beginning.
$('#result').append(step[0][0].childElementCount+"<br>") // #result showing how many child element in #test
        var change = function (){          
        $('.test').append('<div>t</div>')       //every click will a append <div> in #test
        step.push($('.test'))                    // record this move in step[] 
        console.log('step length',step.length)   // total moves
        for ( var i = 0; i < step.length; i++ ) {
        $('#result').append(step[i][0].childElementCount)
        }
        $('#result').append("<br>")}
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop iterations (`i`) should be based on `childElementCount` instead of the `step` array length.

I changed your code to get the last element in the array with `step[step.length-1]`, and changed the for loop to stop when it hits last `childElementCount`. I also called `change()` explicitly to let it do the work of creating and rendering the first element for you to avoid duplicating code.

Fixed Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/8sbq0y0k/

Fixed code:

```js
var step = []; // step is a record of changes in #test.
function change() {
    $('#test').append('<div>t</div>') //every click will a append <div> in #test
    step.push($('#test')) // record this move in step[] 
    console.log('step length', step.length) // total moves
    for (var i = 0; i < step[step.length-1][0].childElementCount; i++) {
        $('#result').append(i.toString())
    }
    $('#result').append("<br/>")
}
change(); // let change do the work for you
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" onclick="change()">Count Child Element</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```